# jsf value expression

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I would like to create contents of my jsf page dynamically. What i have to do, is to build a component-editor. I placed two buttons on my page. Here is the code :

```
//Various imports;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped 
public class Elpad implements Serializable{
  private String padreCorrente = "Nessun padre è stato creato";
  private HtmlPanelGrid customGrid;
  private UIComponent padreCorrenteC;
  private List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
  private List<UISelectItems> listaItem = new ArrayList<UISelectItems>();
  private String itemScelto = "";

public Elpad() {
    //items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    //items.add(0, new SelectItem("poba", "poba"));
    //items.add(1, new SelectItem("ripoba", "ripoba"));
}

public String getItemScelto() {
    return itemScelto;
}

public void setItemScelto(String itemScelto) {
    this.itemScelto = itemScelto;
}
private String ris ="";



public List<SelectItem> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<SelectItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public List<UISelectItems> getListaItem() {
    return listaItem;
}

public void setListaItem(List<UISelectItems> listaItem) {
    this.listaItem = listaItem;
}

public HtmlRadio getSelectedRadio() {
    return selectedRadio;
}

public void setSelectedRadio(HtmlRadio selectedRadio) {
    this.selectedRadio = selectedRadio;
}

public String getPadreCorrente() {
    return padreCorrente;
}

public void setPadreCorrente(String padreCorrente) {
    this.padreCorrente = padreCorrente;
}

public HtmlPanelGrid getCustomGrid() {
    return customGrid;
}

public void setCustomGrid(HtmlPanelGrid customGrid) {
    this.customGrid = customGrid;
}

public void aggiungiPadre(ActionEvent evt) {

    HtmlSelectOneListbox sor = new HtmlSelectOneListbox();
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elcntx = fc.getELContext();
    Application app = fc.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory xprfct = app.getExpressionFactory();
 ValueExpression ve = xprfct.createValueExpression(elcntx,"#{elpad.itemScelto}", String.class);
    ve.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
    sor.setValueExpression("value", ve);

    log.error("Il componente HtmlSelectOneListbox sor è stato creato con ID : " + sor.getClientId() + " e ValueExpression : " + sor.getValueExpression("value") + " quindi ha valore : " + sor.getValue());

    UISelectItems a = new UISelectItems();

    items.add(0, new SelectItem("poba", "poba"));


 ValueExpression ve1 = xprfct.createValueExpression(elcntx,"#{elpad.items}", ArrayList.class);
    ve1.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
    a.setValueExpression("valuee", ve1);

    log.error("Il componente UISelectItems a è stato creato con ID : " + a.getClientId() + " e ValueExpression : " + a.getValueExpression("valuee") + " quindi ha valore : " + a.getValue() + " per l'attributo items : " + items.get(0).getLabel() + " di dimensione : " + items.size() + " ;" );

    sor.getChildren().add(a);



    customGrid.getChildren().add(sor);
    padreCorrenteC = sor;

    /*FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExpression = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{elpad.items}", String.class);

    valueExpression.setValue(elContext, ris);*/



    padreCorrente = padreCorrenteC.getId();
}

public void aggiungiFiglio(ActionEvent evt) {

    items.add(new SelectItem(padreCorrente, padreCorrente.toString()));

}


}
```

And that s my XHTML page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>Cambia padre</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ice:form> 
            <ice:panelGrid binding="#{elpad.customGrid}"> 
            </ice:panelGrid>
            <ice:commandButton value="Aggiungi padre" actionListener="#    {elpad.aggiungiPadre}"></ice:commandButton>
            <ice:commandButton value="Aggiungi figlio" actionListener="#    {elpad.aggiungiFiglio}"></ice:commandButton>
        </ice:form>
        <ice:outputLabel value="#{elpad.padreCorrente}"></ice:outputLabel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me? What i am trying to do is to create a SelectOneList with a SelectItems child with the first button, and to add items to the list with the second button. I think i m missing something on creation of the second ValueExpression (because i tried some tests with the logger and it returns null) but i don't know what

Comment: You should execute an action in the `action` tag attribute of the `<ice:commandButton` tag component, not in the `actionListener`. Also, you should read [The benefits and pitfalls of @ViewScoped](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html): *In a nutshell: the @ViewScoped breaks when any UIComponent is bound to the bean using binding attribute...* It would be better (for this case) to use a `@SessionScoped` to make your test work and it would be better to not binding components at all.

Comment: Hi..Thank you for the answer. I have to do this, because my teacer wants to be able to create custom tests. For example, a test can be composed by a textarea, a checkbox, and a button. Or 3 radio buttons and a commandbutton. So he wants a editor, and the only way i found to create something like that is using the component binding.. But if i use the action tag attribute, the page will be reloaded?

Comment: I haven't worked with ICEFaces, but I suppose there must be a way to tell the component that it's executing an Ajax request. It would be good to read the [ICEFaces Documentation](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/documentation.jsf). If you don't want/need to use ICEFaces for this, you can use `<h:commandButton>` with `<f:ajax>` too as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/)

Comment: I m sorry for bad english, i try to explain what i have to do. The project consists in creating a web application. My teacher wants a platform that allows him to create custom tests. I mean, he will have a sort of editor. He will chose the UI components to place in each question of the test, and he will customize the component. For example, if he wants to create a multiple-choice-question, he will place a label, and he will customize the label with the text of the question. Then he will place a 3 items radio button component (a SelectOneRadio component with 3 child-items)

Comment: I thought that using a "actionListener" was a sort of "push" , to update the current page without reloading it (that' s what appens if i use the "action" property). I also have to create "manually" the binding for each component. That s why a simple test could be "write the java method  String helloworld(); and one of the buttons placed may be used for validating the code , and another for submit the answer.. Is it understandable?

Comment: it looks more like a design problem because you must not bind the bean properties to a random JSF compoment that could be or not be used at all. The assignment your teacher has let you is not for JSF starters (and you look like being in learning phase). I'll suggest you to have component templates for the questions or ask your teacher for better guidance in this project.

Comment: thank you.. will you add me to skype? my contact is jkl807.. it ll be very usefull to make you some questions .. it ll take just a few minutes, please :- )